# unable to mount any drive that working fine on windows

Tags: mount, hibernate, unmount, restricted-access

Whenever I boot Ubuntu, I get a message that it cannot mount my windows partition, and I can choose to either wait, skip or manually mount.

When I try to enter my Windows partition through Nautilus I get a message saying that this partition is hibernated and that I need to enter the file system and properly close it, something I have done with no problem so I don't know why this happens.

Here's my partition table, if any more data is needed please let me know.

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    20000767     9999360   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        20002814   478001151   228999169    5  Extended
/dev/sda3   *   478001152   622532607    72265728    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       622532608   625141759     1304576   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda5        20002816   478001151   228999168   83  Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't hibernated Windows, then this can happen because of the "fast startup" option in Windows.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUb20.png)

Simply boot into Windows, uncheck this box, and you should be fine. To get to that window in the screenshot, open the start menu, and search for "Power Options". Click “Choose what the power buttons do” on the left side of the window. Click “Change settings that are currently unavailable.” Then, uncheck it.